# Dojo FilteringSelect - prevent automatic dropdown opening

Tags: javascript, dojo

I'm using `dojo.form.FilteringSelect` as a google-like suggester. Based on the string typed, I get a list of values through AJAX and put them into the widget's store. This process is launched after every `keyUp`. The problem I have, is that the dropdownlist gets open automatically, trying to find in its store (populated by the old values) the string typed, before the AJAX Response arrives. I would like to disable this behaviour and call `openDropDown()` myself, after I have the result. Is there any elegant way of doing this? Something like:

```
var fs = new dojo.form.FilteringSelect({
    automaticDropDown: false // I am looking for a property like this one
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't really think that there is a way to easily do this. What you do (as far as I understand) is that you bind an `keyUp` event handler and modify the store manually.

The best thing to do is that you create your own store (or use `dojo/store/JsonRest` maybe) and override the `query()` function. This function is actually responsible for giving you a subset of the data that matches the query. If you want to change the data that is returned from the store when that query is executed, then you should modify it there.

The benefit from this approach is that you don't need to define your own event handler and start to filter the store yourself from the outside because that's already implemented in another way. The dropdown will only be opened after the `query()` function is executed, so then you don't have a problem with the order of execution.

Comment: Hm, maybe `dojox.data.JsonRestStore` is more suitable for this. However, after having swum in the dojo source code for over a week, I came to the conclusion that it would be much easier to use `ValidationTextBox` and write the suggester all on my own and that's what I did. Thank you for the help.